# Overlap in labels of point data in rasterVis

Tags: r, r-raster, levelplot, rastervis

I have a raster `r`, one polygon shapefile `regions` and a point shapefile `cities`. I need to plot all three into one map layout. In addition to this I need to label point file with names of cities (`cities$city$Town.Name`) and their temperature and precipitation value (assigned as `cities$labels`). So I have used the following code with packages 'raster' and 'rasterVis'.

```
p1<-levelplot(regions.r,par.settings=mytheme,scales=list(draw=FALSE),xlab="",ylab="",margin=F)+
  layer(sp.polygons(regions))+
          layer(sp.points(cities,pch=20,cex=1.5,col="black"))
p1+
  layer(sp.text(coordinates(cities), txt = cities$city$Town.Name, pos = 3,col="black",font=list(face="bold"),cex=0.8))+
  layer(sp.text(coordinates(cities),txt = cities$label,
                pos = 1,cex=0.6,col="black"))#Add shapefile labels
```

This works fine when area has scattered cities distribution (see figure below).
[image]
However, if the cities are concentrated in one part I experience overlap of labels (see figure below). Is there a way to avoid the label overlap?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `maptools::sp.pointLabel` function?

Comment: Thanks, Oscar! This worked perfectly for me.